# MYSQL same table has different date formats

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table which is populated with data from an external source. The problem is I am getting two different format of dates for the same column, there are some records in `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'` format and other in `'%Y-%d-%m %H:%i%s'` format and they are all `VARCHAR` type.

I know how to convert a string type date field to a date/datetime field but how do I handle discrepancies in the way the dates are coming? Is it possible to Update dates on the basis of their individual format, so that I can apply a `WHERE` condition for updates to take place ONLY `WHERE date_field` is of `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'` format, and then another query to make updates for date field in `'%Y-%d-%m %H:%i%s'` format?

Right now when I try updating the tables with a common query I get error for the fields which donot match the format:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_date_field = STR_TO_DATE(my_date_field,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

**RESPONSE: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '10-22-12 15:00' for function str_to_date**

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_date_field = STR_TO_DATE(my_date_field,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%i');
```

**RESPONSE: Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2010-01-01 00:00:00'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for this value `10-22-12 15:00` you should use, `%y-%d-%m %H:%i`

while for `2010-01-01 00:00:00`, it should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`

so your query will use `CASE`

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_date_field = (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(my_date_field) = 14 
                          THEN STR_TO_DATE(my_date_field,'%y-%d-%m %H:%i')
                          ELSE STR_TO_DATE(my_date_field,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
                      END)
```

- [See SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ae1d/1)

Other Source

- [DATE Formats](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly. I completely forgot I could use case. Thank you.

Comment: Added demonstration link :D

Comment: Thank you for added demonstration links.

Answer (score 0):

you can not update like that because if there is data in that column and it is of different type then you can not update table column so you should delete the column or make a procedure for that in that you can check and the replace or update table.

Comment: So I can not filter dates from my table on the basis of their format?